# Youtube API v3 Get Video using PlaylistItems.list

Tags: youtube-data-api

I developed an integration with Youtube two years ago to retrieve video url's. But last month it started to fail.
My process is:

- Using Channels.list and passing UserId we obtain a list of Uploads from:  channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads
- With this id we use the method: PlayListItems.List passing uploads id in playlistRequest.PlaylistId. We receive a list of playlistItems.

This two calls are working fine. We are obtaining a list of videos.

But when we try to retrieve a video to get the URL we are receiving a 500 error.

PlayListItems.List

- Id: VVV0MUNhMG5rWDdVa3J0REFNVk5jTEhRLnFJMURfb0dhYXBj
- Part: Snippet
- Response:

  {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
     {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "backendError",
      "message": "Backend Error"
     }
    ],
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Backend Error"
  }
  }

Example Calls:

Channels.list:

- id: UCt1Ca0nkX7UkrtDAMVNcLHQ
- Part: ContentDetails

PlayListItems.List:

- Part = snippet
- PlayListId: UUt1Ca0nkX7UkrtDAMVNcLHQ

PlayListItems.List:

- Part: Snippet
- Id: VVV0MUNhMG5rWDdVa3J0REFNVk5jTEhRLnFJMURfb0dhYXBj

any idea why is now failing?

Comment: I just checked, all your requests are correctly working. AFAIK YouTube Data API v3 "backend error" code is just like "transient error" it appears and disappears by being unlucky or lucky.